# Stopping SAP GUI search before timeout with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm working on an Excel-VBA-controlled SAP GUI script that does some searching based on user's input. For some input values, the search can take a long time or even time-out.

I'd like VBA to end SAP transaction after the SAP transaction has been searching for more than 30 seconds. I'm not sure how to accomplish this without being able to setup excel for multithreading. I haven't had much success with application.ontime either...

```
    'inputs users info into T-Code search inputs
    'executes the search by hitting f8
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
```

The actual SAP search is triggered with:

```
    .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
```

I'd like a method to make VBA kill the SAP transaction if more than 30 seconds have passed after the search was executed and search is still on-going.